# C# WPF application datagrid error: object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, wpf, object, datagrid

I am a newbie with `DataGrid`s in WPF C#.

I have two `DataGrid`s on two different tab controls.

Now one of them works (which means I am able to dynamically create and add columns and access datagrid1 and its methods)
While with other one datagrid2 I am not able to do the above in any private methods. (I copy pasted datagrid1 properties and renamed it datagrid2)
However with datagrid2, when I use inside the Windows_Loaded method, I am able to do these things.

What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
<my3:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
CanUserDeleteRows="False" Block.TextAlignment="Center" HeadersVisibility="Column"  
AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" 
AlternatingRowBackground="LightYellow" Margin="6,57.772,12.489,6" Name="datagrid2" 
xmlns:my3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
</my3:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Code didn't make it through...

Comment: @LalaTrivedi - What problem solving steps have you taken to solve the problem?  The code you posted isn't `C#` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, never try to access and manipulate `UIElement`s in the constructor.

Instead, handle the `Loaded` event of your container (usually a `UserControl`, `Control`, `Window`, or `Page`) and manipulate your `UIElement`s there.

Comment: Ok. But how come I was able to use datagrid1 in private methods all over the windows controls and not with datagrid2?

Comment: I believe the "InitializeComponent()" call is asynchronous. Which means, you don't know when it will end. There's a chance the app had the time to process your first grid but not the second one. Try moving everything to the Loaded event (including your grid1 stuff) and see if it fixes your issue. If it doesn't, the problem is elsewhere ;)

Comment: Yes. Joe is right...the InitializeComponent() is pretty async..Hence waiting for all controls etc to load up properly and then using the data grid...It so happened that I was trying to use to before it was intialized hence the error...Sorry i didnt post a C# code. I am total newbie with stack overflow and this was my first post. I'll be careful next time

Comment: Just so you know, I believe there's a property called "IsInitialized" that you can check to see if a visual element is ready to be used.